# mix-up WebForm and MVC in one project vs separate them in 2 projects in the same solution

Tags: asp.net

I've tried to mix up WebForm and MVC in the same application, but so far I've failed miserably. It looks like I'm missing some steps some how some where. I'm really tired.

I wonder if just it's bad prectice to have 3 projects in a solution: The first one for the Model, the second one for the Webform, and the last one for the MVC.

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have two separate projects one for MVC and one for classic WebForms it's like you have two distinct web applications. Those two should be deployed separately in different virtual folders in IIS.

On the other hand you have the possibility to [mix classic WebForms and ASP.NET MVC](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/PlugInHybridsASPNETWebFormsAndASPMVCAndASPNETDynamicDataSideBySide.aspx) in the same project.

Usually people have some legacy WebForms application that they want to migrate in ASP.NET MVC. But due to the sheer amount of code this cannot be done at once so you would create a new ASP.NET MVC application and import the existing legacy WebForms inside it which could be directly used. Then you could progressively update legacy code to the MVC pattern.

But from personal experience I find it dirty mixing classic WebForms with ASP.NET MVC. My hands just feel dirty. What I do is that I would keep legacy WebForms as a separate application and start replacing different sections of it with a new ASP.NET MVC application and the two of them would communicate only through standard HTTP techniques (usually GET and POST verbs).

Comment: That's interesting. But, My question is to know if keeping the WebForm and MVC in 2 separate projects is considered to be bad practice. Given also your feeling about the mix up of types, I've get the same feeling about not mixing them up either.

Comment: @Richard77, if you want to talk about *bad practices* you will have to provide much more details about your scenario. Talking about whether having 2 or 3 projects in a Visual Studio Solution where you would hardly make sense. So what is your scenario? What are you trying to do? What problems have you encountered? ... So don't expect a non-subjective answer to what appears to be an unclear question and undefined scenario and context.

Comment: I'm fine with your answer. But, I wanted you to tell me if they are pros and cons related to either choice. Thanks.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov: I agree with it feeling dirty, but could you elaborate on the implications of routing these pages on the same domain? It seems that this is very convenient with MVC's RouteConfig, whereas I am unsure how to achieve such a transparent division in IIS. Do you run the old pages in a sub-directory, thus breaking URLs for the old site?